# have: command not found

Tags: bash, grub2

I have created my own [linux](http://github.com/PandaLinux/base-64). Whenever I open up my bash and login into a sub-shell I get the following error

```
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
-bash: have: command not found
```

It is displayed several times. To debug it, I executed the following command:

```
bash --login -x
```

Output:

```
+ source /etc/locale.conf
++ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
+ for f in '/etc/bash_completion.d/*'
+ '[' -e /etc/bash_completion.d/grub ']'
+ source /etc/bash_completion.d/grub
+++ echo grub-set-default
+++ sed s,x,x,
++ __grub_set_default_program=grub-set-default
++ have grub-set-default
bash: have: command not found
++ unset __grub_set_default_program
+++ sed s,x,x,
+++ echo grub-reboot
++ __grub_reboot_program=grub-reboot
++ have grub-reboot
bash: have: command not found
++ unset __grub_reboot_program
+++ echo grub-editenv
+++ sed s,x,x,
++ __grub_editenv_program=grub-editenv
++ have grub-editenv
bash: have: command not found
```

The output is too long too be pasted here. But this snippet shows the error. The error is in the `/etc/bash_completion.d/grub` file. This file is calling `have`. Re-installing grub didn't fix the error. So, how do I solve this bug?

Comment: Crossposted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/778439/have-command-not-found

Comment: What is `have`?  Where did it come from?  It looks on context more like a comment that's attempting to be run as a command rather than an actual binary.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are missing bash completion in your Linux.

See this post also ['have' keyword for bash completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874920/have-keyword-for-bash-completion)

Answer (score 2):

I got the problem after updating my debian server:

```
bigbear3001@server:/etc/openvpn$ sudo su -
-su: have: command not found
-su: have: command not found
...
```

I fixed it by commenting out the following lines in /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion at the end

```
unset -f have
unset have
```

Of course you can also fix all the scripts using `have` instead of `_have`

Comment: I have never had this issue before, but I have it now on Arch Linux with the completions of `grub2:2.06.r456.g65bc45963-1`. This helped me, but I am considering reporting it upstream.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue after I'd installed *git completion*.
The problem resolved by commenting these strings in *.bashrc* :

```
#Git completion script
#for file in /etc/bash_completion.d/* ; do 
#       source "$file"
#done
```

So, now it works clear:

```
user@linux~>
```

and no

```
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
 have: command not found
```

Comment: the issue is if you comment out that for statement, you won't get the benefit of the custom completion scripts in the /etc/bash_completion.d directory.  I vote this response down.  But I am having the same issue with the custom grub auto-completion found in /etc/bash_completion.d directory.  so doing '. /etc/bash_completion' is not working as expected.

Comment: @RaymondBurkholder Thank you for your response. That issue occurred after I tried to install completion for git in .bashrc. Perhaps you are right: recently after reinstalling the OS, I found git completion works by default without any scripts in .bashrc. But in that time I used the script for completion. That's why I wrote about it here.